# Improve Java code: too many if's

Tags: java, optimization, if-statement

I have several cases and I am just using simple `if ... if else` blocks.

How can I reduce the number of `if` statements in this code?

Perhaps I could use a lookup table, but I am not sure how to implement it in Java.

```
private int transition(char current, int state)
{
    if(state == 0)
    {
        if(current == 'b')
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    if(state == 1)
    {
        if(current == 'a')
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    if(state == 2)
    {
        if(current == 's')
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    if(state == 3)
    {
        if(current == 'e')
        {
            return 3;
        }
        if(current == 'b')
        {
            return 4;
        }
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    if(state == 4)
    {
        if(current == 'a')
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    if(state == 5)
    {
        if(current == 'l')
        {
            return 6;
        }
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look Ma' so many Magic Numbers! Consider using some named constants instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc. Because in 6 months nobody will remember what 1 or 2 were supposed to mean.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Even though I could not accept all the solutions, I learned a bit more about coding from each of your answers, so I greatly appreciate the help. Have a great Sunday.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you're trying to do looks very much like a finite state machine, and these are usually implemented with the help of a transition table. Once you set up the table, it's simply a matter of indexing to the position you want to get the return value. Assuming your return values are all less than 256, you can use a 2D byte array:

```
byte table[][] = new byte[NUM_STATES][NUM_CHARACTERS];
// Populate the non-zero entries of the table
table[0]['b'] = 1;
table[1]['a'] = 2;
// etc...

private int transition(char current, int state) {
  return table[state][current];
}
```

Comment: Haha this is exactly what I was looking for. I am actually implementing a finite state machine.

Comment: I'd accept this one if I were you.  It's by far the best answer.

Comment: It would be the fastest-performance... except it requires all of the entries in the table to be populated. Not great when you compare things like `if (current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z') { do something ... }`

Answer (score 14):

Well, you can easily utilize [hash](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Simple and clean.

```
    // declare hashtable
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("0-b", 1);
    map.put("1-a", 2);
    map.put("2-s", 3);
    ...

    // get result
    Integer result = map.get(state + "-" + current);
    // change null (nothing found) to zero
    return result == null ? 0 : result;
```

Comment: Performance wise, wouldn't it be better to create a new class that holds a digit and char and have it have a hash function that generates a unique hash so that the hash table can perform faster?

Comment: @mathepic Certainly, there's lots of room for improvement. (Although you may find that creating unique hash function isn't always easy, especially as number of states grow). I just wanted to provide simple and clean example of lookup table.  And it's not like HashMap has that much overhead comparing to other methods, like one- or two-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Yeah, I was just making a suggestion. +1.

Answer (score 9):

consider interfaces + enums:

```
interface State<T>
{
    public void State<T> step(T input);
}

enum MyState implements State<Character> {
    STATE0(0) { @Override public void MyState step(Character c) { return c == 'b' ? STATE1 : STATE0; }},
    STATE1(1) { @Override public void MyState step(Character c) { return c == 'a' ? STATE2 : STATE0; }},

    /* rest of states here */

    final private int value;
    MyState(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public int getValue() { return this.value; }
}

class SomeClass
{
   public MyState currentState = STATE0;

   public void step(char input)
   {
      this.currentState = this.currentState.step(input);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

i switch statement would be best here:

```
private int transition(char current, int state)
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case 0:
            return current == 'b' ? 1 : 0;
        case 1:
            return current == 'a' ? 2 : 0;
        case 2:
            return current == 's' ? 3 : 0;
        case 3:
            return current == 'e' ? 3 : (current == 'b' ? 4 : 0);
        case 4:
            return current == 'a' ? 5 : 0;
        case 5:
            return current == 'l' ? 6 : 0;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

And a note, theres only 5 if statements there checking pure intergers, this is not exactly an overhead.

Comment: @RobertPitt Thanks! I appreciate the extra feedback.

Comment: to shrink the code even more, if you use short hand logicals and you keep them to 1 line you can then remove the `break;` commands, IF java has that within its interpretor.

Comment: You don't really need _brake_ if you have _return_, right? Could make it a bit smaller.

Comment: I am pretty sure using break after a return is invalid and causes compile errors.

Comment: @Willi is absolutely correct. I took the liberty to make the code in the answer compile.

Comment: ive never worked with Java, I was just writing the code that would usually fit into all languages, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you need a better abstraction for a finite state machine.  Think about a class that encapsulates what you want in a better way so you can extend it by configuration rather than modifying code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was worried that I was hard coding too much. I will reconsider the way I am going about it.

Comment: +1 In my humble opinion the best suggestion here. When I see lots of if's, the first thing comming to my mind is 'Use Inheritance'.

Comment: As a general rule, you can *always* replace conditions with polymorphism. After all, what *is* dynamic method dispatch if not a giant switch statement? Smalltalk, for example, does not have *any* conditionals, *everything* is done through method dispatch.

Comment: True, you can always replace conditions with polymorphism, but I wouldn't agree that it's always the best solution.  In this case, polymorphism would result in lots of small classes, and it may not be the most declarative.  I'd prefer a declarative solution here.

Answer (score 5):

If this code is about to be expanded over the time, why not use a state machine? Each state will return the next state based on the character it receives. Maybe it's an overkill for this code, but it'll be a lot easier to maintain, expand & read.

Answer (score 2):

Use `switch` statement for the outer `if` chain:

```
switch (state) {
  case 0: <code> ; break;
  case 1: <code> ; break;
  case 2: <code> ; break;
  <etc>
  default: return 0; break;
}
```